# JavaScript : Get inputText value in a table cell

Tags: javascript

I used the following code to insert new rows.

```
function NewInputText(_id,_width,_readOnly,_value)
{
    return "<input id='"+_id+"' readonly="+_readOnly+" type='text' value='"+_value+"'/>";
}
```

How can I get this inputText's values from any cell?

Important: I don't need the innerHTML string, I just want the value from inputText in any of the table cells.

Answer (score 0):

You may need:

```
var val = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
```

**after** your `<input>` is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this  element was already added to your HTML, your get the value of an  element via the `value` property. You could also just use `_value` again, but I don't know your full code.

And you should consider using CSS to design your input-boxes. You might also want to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` if you're *not inserting any HTML elements*.

Answer (score -1):

You have something like below, to get the exact value and not innerHTML:

```
function getValue(_id) {
    return document.getElementById(_id).value;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with above solution?